# Exception raised during rendering: android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout cannot be cast to android.preference.Preference

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm trying to create a settings window for my app with a toolbar above to enter back button and more. But I always this error.

Error 
Exception raised during rendering: android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout cannot be cast to android.preference.Preference

preferenze.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <PreferenceCategory>
        <ListPreference android:key="colore"
            android:summary="ciao"
            android:title="About "
            android:defaultValue="#000000"
            android:dialogTitle="colore di sfondo" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

settings.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_tips"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context="com.example.twisterandroid.Tips_5">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <include layout="@xml/preferenze"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```